# Best practices for querying large Oracle dumps

Tags: c#, oracle10g

My customer wants to consolidate information from two oracle dumps into a report. These dumps are placed on a server by some interval and are both there size are about 5GB.
I need to read the data from both dumps and group them into something useful. The big issue here is the performance, so my question is: How should you handle these kind of dumps, in a way that the performance stays acceptable?

The relation of the dumps look like this:

Orders(DUMP1) 1---* (DUMP1)products 1---* (DUMP2)transactions

I hope you can give some guidance in how to approach such a project with large data queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

I replicated the businness domain of customer and used NHibernate for my mappings, since NHibernate can map to a Oracle 10G database.
We created some usefull criteria's that collect the data and use these criteria's for building up the reports.
This implementation uses the build-in Caching options from NHibernate and works very well. I had to tune the resulting queries a bit after investigating them with NHProfiler.

**Summary**

1. Replicated the businness domain
2. Mapped the .NET entities to the Oracle 10G database with NHibernate
3. Defined some usefull criteria's (queries)
4. Implemented a DataCollector class wich uses the criteria's created in step 3
5. Build some reports by using this DataCollector class